# Expresso Store Promo Code Use In Email?

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce

Can I use a promo code variable in the email for new orders? The client would like to be notified of the promo code used in the email itself, which gets bcc'ed to them as well as the buyer. Something like this:

```
Order Id    - {order_id}
Order Total - {order_total}
Voucher (if used): {promo_code}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can include the `{promo_code}` and `{promo_value}` in your email templates if you want to. If you want to show the total discount on the order then use `{order_discount}`.